# This is MobileServiceProvider Java Program Problem

Tags: java

***I need help with how to get those private final values from the MobileServiceProvider Class to make it works to my MobileSericeProviderTest Class.***
Description: Design a class that calculates a customer's monthly bill.It should store the letter of the package the customer has purchased (A, B, or C) and the number of miniutes that were used. it should have a method that returns the total charges. Demonstrate the class in a program that asks the user to select a package and enter the number of minutes used. The program should display the total charges.

```js
package mobileserviceprovider;

public  class MobileServiceProvider 
{
    private final double COST_A = 39.99;
    private final double COST_B = 59.99;
    private final double COST_C = 69.99;
    private final int MIN_A = 450;
    private final int MIN_B = 900;
    private final double OVER_A = 0.45;
    private final double OVER_B = 0.40;
    String customer_Package;
    double customer_TimeUse;

    MobileServiceProvider() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    
    public double getCostA()
    {
        return COST_A;
    } 
    
    public int getMinA()
    {
        return MIN_A;
    } 
    
    public String getPackage()
    {
        return customer_Package; 
    }
    
    public double getHours()
    {
        return customer_TimeUse;
    }
    
    public void setPackage( String customer_Package )
    {
        this.customer_Package = customer_Package;
    }        
    
    public void setHours( double customer_TimeUse )
    {
        this.customer_TimeUse = customer_TimeUse;
    }   
    
    public MobileServiceProvider( String pack, double time )
    { 
      customer_Package = pack;
      customer_TimeUse = time;
      

      {
      }
      
      }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

```html
package mobileserviceprovider;

import java.util.Scanner; 
public class MobileServiceProviderTest 
{

  
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String enter_Package = null;
        double enter_Hours;
        double min_A;
        double bill;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your package type?");
        keyboard.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("How many hours did you use for this package?");
        enter_Hours = keyboard.nextDouble();
        
        keyboard.nextLine();
        
        MobileServiceProvider calMobileSP = new MobileServiceProvider();
        calMobileSP.setPackage(enter_Package);
        calMobileSP.setHours(enter_Hours);
        calMobileSP.getMinA();
        
        switch ( enter_Package)
        {
            case "A":
            {
                if (enter_Hours <= MIN_A)
                    bill = COST_A;
                else
                    bill = COST_A + OVER_A * (enter_Hours - MIN_A)
                    }
            
            
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not make these final fields public? It looks like you define here constants. Usually such constants are declared "public static final ...". Since both classes are in the same package, it would also be enough to declare them package visible ("static final ..."). BTW: your enter_Package is still null in the switch (never assigned).

Comment: I was thinking that. However, I think my professor wants it to be private final double. But I was wondering that constants shouldn't be private right ? But he said make them private so they are protected information.